# Losing Data Repeated Call To Method

Tags: python, function

I realize this question has been asked and answered in the past, but I'm having trouble adjusting my method to avoid data loss after repeated calls.

My method:

```
def getColumn(self, name):
    index_num = self.headers.index(str(name))
    columns = [item[index_num] for item in self.container]
    acco = self.accounts
    del acco[0]
    del columns[0]
    columns = [item.replace(',', '') for item in columns]
    return dict(zip(acco, columns))
```

self.container is an array with a header that has the following form:

```
[['ACCOUNT', 'VALUE1', 'VALUE2'],
 ['Account1', '3.43', '2.5'],
 ['Account2', '1,235.67', '8.98']]
```

self.accounts is defined by `return [item[0] for item in self.container`

What i'm trying to do is zip up the accounts and values in a dictionary by passing a string to match one of the header names. The method looks up the index in the header, and then attempts to pull out the column of values and delete the header.

Each subsequent call to this method results in a dictionary who's length decreases by 1 for each call. When I pass 'VALUE1' in, the length is 26. When I then pass 'VALUE2', its length is 25, so on.

Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish this without losing data on subsequent calls to the method?

Comment: what happens if you pass 'VALUE1', 'VALUE2' and then again 'VALUE1' ?

Comment: There are many ways to do that - for example, keep a state variable (self.next, for example), indicating the index of the next variable to get. However, this looks like a very bad class design - are you sure that there isn't a better way to arrange things?

Comment: It continues to lose values. After passing 'VALUE1' again the length decreases to 24.

Comment: @GuyAdini haha, I'm sure it is a bad class design. I'm pretty new to programming, trying to learn how to do these things properly.

Comment: Did you try by just replacing "acco = self.accounts[:]" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need to see how your self.accounts property is actually implemented, but I am almost certain your problem is in your use of the **del** builtin.  There are very few reasons, especially in something this simple, to use **del** and especially with mutable types (ie lists) it can lead to some very strange behaviors.  I'm guessing that your problem lies in these two lines:

```
acco = self.accounts
del acco[0]
```

Which are effectively doing this:

```
del self.accounts[0]
```

You might find that this fixes it:

```
acco = self.accounts[:] # makes a shallow copy of self.accounts
del acco[0]
```

The easiest way to debug is to simply put print statements above and below showing you the length of the self.accounts object itself.

I still suggest not using **del** and consider the list.pop method instead.  And, more importantly, consider reimplementing your self.container as a dictionary, as the "lists of lists" way of modeling spreadsheet data isn't really that efficient.

Comment: That did it. Appreciate the advice.